# BindingExpression path error: 'IsDropDownOpen' property not found on 'object'

Tags: xaml

I'm facing a binding error mentioned in the output window as follows.

Error:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'IsDropDownOpen' property not found on 'object' ''SaveEnterpriseView'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen;
>   DataItem='SaveEnterpriseView' (Name=''); target element is
>   'RibbonButton' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type
>   'Object')"

Here is my xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project1.Views.SaveEnterpriseView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ribbon="clrnamespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
             xmlns:base="clr-namespace:Project1.WPF;assembly=Project1">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{BindingSaveEnterpriseCommand}" Label="{base:TextID _SaveEnterprise}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template> 
</UserControl>
```

From this link [WPF Ribbon: DataTemplate causes BindingExpression path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276010/wpf-ribbon-datatemplate-causes-bindingexpression-path-error), I assume this problem is related to ribbonbutton itself. But I'm uanble to find the fix for this.